# Como utilizar o Firebase

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, firebase, modelagem

Galera, estou precisando utilizar o firebase para meu TCC do técnico, porém, sempre usei o sqlserver mesmo, sou acostumado com a linguagem SQL. Alguém poderia me dar uma base de como eu posso por exemplo criar uma tabela de usuário com nome telefone etc? tipo, a modelagem em si, eu não consegui fazer nada além da conexão com android e o registro e login com email, isso foi suave, vi um tutorial, mas fora isso, não consegui nada.

Comment: Olá Aken, boas vindas ao Stack Overflow. Por favor, veja este [artigo sobre Como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e adeque sua dúvida, assim a comunidade pode contribuir de maneira mais pontual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para facilitar sua vida, conselho criar uma classe para pegar facilmente a instancia:

Minha classe do firebase:

```java
    public final class ConfiguracaoFirebase {

        private static DatabaseReference referenciaFireBase;
        private static FirebaseAuth auth;

        public static DatabaseReference getFirebase() {

            if(referenciaFireBase == null)
             referenciaFireBase  = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

            return referenciaFireBase;
        }

        public static FirebaseAuth getAutenticacao()
        {
            if(auth == null)
                auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            return auth;
        }
    }


    public class MainActivity{

            private DatabaseReference mUsuarioDb; 

           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


               // criando tabela
                mUsuarioDb = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase().child("usuario");

                mUsuarioDb.child("nome").setValue("usuarioNome");
                mUsuarioDb.child("telefone").setValue("usuarioTel");
           }
    }
```

Estou fazendo um projeto todo em firebase, segue o link do projeto, pode usar a vontade: 
[github.com/jony5ds/whats_app_clone](https://github.com/jony5ds/whats_app_clone)

Comment: Valeu, vou dar uma olhada :)

Comment: Qualquer duvida só falar, estou trabalhando em um projeto com firebase, acredito que esse projeto possa te ajudar bastante